# Is it possible to simulate a quantum algorithm on a classical computer?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, simulation

I am designing a quantum algorithm that I would like to simulate and test, but I need to be able to simulate it on a classical computer.

Comment: see eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22015/55

Comment: You have various simulators available on different platforms. For instance, with IBM devices, if you log in to the IBM quantum experience you can see the different simulators and real devices. You can also try to implement your own but it is hard work.